# Insertion of term into Contract for Sale under UK law when other party under actual notice?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, sale-of-goods

I'm working through currently trying to solve a problem question which concerns a contractual dispute arising out of an international contract for the sale of goods on CIF INCOTERMS 2020 terms with the law of the united kingdom ( e.g. SoGA 1979) being the applicable law to this contract, as agreed by the parties. The parties have agreed to shipment in July. I am advising the parties with respect to any claims they may have.

As part of the problem, I do not have access to the full terms of the contract for sale. However, the letter of credit facility opened by the buyer contains a stipulation that the goods are to arrive in September. **The seller is made aware of this condition but does not pay attention to it.** The seller then ships the goods as normal, however such goods arrive in October.

My question therefore is can the buyer rely on this condition so inserted given that the seller was on actual notice of that inserted term in the context of an international sale of goods contract? I'm aware that the seller's conduct could amount to acceptance of this term given that they were aware of it and failed to protest it. I would really appreciate some UK case law which considers this in the context of the sale of goods internationally.